# Swift - UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching ignores a section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm struggling with prefetching data when user scrolls through a section.

I have 3 sections, when user scrolls through a section, it should load more data to that section.

I'm trying to do that using `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` where I check section and item number.

**Here is my testing code:**

```
extension DiscoverVC: UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        let section = indexPaths.map({ $0.section }).max() ?? 0
        let item = indexPaths.map({ $0.item }).max() ?? 0
        
        switch section {
        case 0:
            if item == 5 {
                print("Section \(section), Row \(item) - Loading more...")
            }
            break
        case 1:
            if item == 5 {
                print("Section \(section), Row \(item) - Loading more...")
            }
            break
        case 2:
            if item == 5 {
                print("Section \(section), Row \(item) - Loading more...")
            }
            break
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason it ignores section 2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/23iOt.jpg (gifs of my phone screen and console)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on this method to get called for every cell/section. You may see it getting called if you add more sections and scroll.

From [apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/1771767-collectionview) "The collection view calls this method as the user scrolls, providing the index paths for cells it is likely to display in the near future[...] The collection view does not call this method for cells it requires immediately, so your code must not rely on this method to load data."

In your example it looks like when you start scrolling you hit the 3rd section right away, without much lead-up, so you're probably hitting the "cells it requires immediately" case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you suggest any solution to my problem?

Comment: No problem. You'll have to do something like trigger necessary fetches in cellForItemAtIndexPath as a fallback in case prefetching didn't get triggered. I can't really give more of an answer without knowing what your requirement/goals are.

Comment: Feel free to post a new question with the details and link it here.